# Htaccess stops working after added new user

Tags: apache, .htpasswd

I have an htpasswd file with one user, it totally works.
But, when I add a user the first user can login but the second user can't.

What might be the problem?

The htpasswd file:

```
user1:$2y$11$I.Czgwna6mzUoqS6TxISrOPoWL.X.AAlfboiSVpHwt2vL2D7CqVkW
user2:$2y$11$Gd0fMTkwa//Rh6ISOpsvQOjuWWIai0Z6YEAzSUvoUPV0r6BzYvrt6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow multiple users to access your site via htpasswd the instructions are in the link below.

Section "Letting more than one person in" [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html#lettingmorethanonepersonin)